# CSS: how to put one image and one block with two <p> in one line not using float

Tags: html, css, image

I want to put one image and one block with two

in one line,
but if use float on image,
it will be out of that big block' border.
I don't want to add height to the big block,
because sometimes image doesn't exit.
like this link: images and (p1 + p2 )  in one line.
http://verygif.com/bbs/b/src/138002270032.jpg
sorry for can't post images.

```
big_block {
border:2px solid #333;
}


<div class="big_block">
{if img exit }<img .... />{/if}
<p>sometext,sometext,sometext,sometext</p>
<p>fulltext,fulltext,fulltext,fulltext</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what language does {if img exit}{/if} come from? I've never seen that in CSS.

Comment: It is not in CSS , it is in a Smarty template.

Comment: Plus, it should be `.big_block { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare `overflow: hidden;` on the parent `<div>` container. That will clear the float and ensures that the image does not go beyond the parent's borders by ensuring that the parents wrap around the paragraphs AND the image.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/8aeAL/

Comment: The `.fix` class simply has the `overflow: hidden;` rule added :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `display: inline` to `<p>` tags,

```
p { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  display: inline; 
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/tpD2u

Comment: Yes...in case no use of inline-block here. Thanks updating the code.

Comment: I had trydisplay inline

Comment: I had try display inline, if you had two <p> you will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I always use something like this:

```
.big_block img { float: left; }
.big_block:after { display: block; cler: both; content: " "; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QWm4T/